# Matching variable value and setting default

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a variable that can take any of the values `"SUBSCRIPT"`, `"ITERATE"`, `"COUNTER"`.

How can I test the variable in any of those, and default to `"SUBSCRIPT"` in case of no match ?

I want a compact form and came up with the following

```
  [[ "${signal}" == "SUBSCRIPT" || "${signal}" == "ITERATE" ||
     "${signal}" == "COUNTER" ]] || signal="SUBSCRIPT"
```

Could the aforementioned fail?

Comment: Your shown code works for me.

Comment: @Cyrus: if this code works, then it shouldn't: the string comparison operator is "=", not "=="

Comment: `==` is correct with `[[...]]`. See: `help [[`.

Comment: @bakunin `==` does a globbing match when used within `[[ ... ]]`. Since the glob patterns used are literal strings, the effect is identical to string comparisons.

Comment: @bakunin, [both `=` and `==` do the same in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html). `==` isn't standard, but then neither is `[[` and as far as I can tell the shells that support the latter support both versions of the operator, with the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your code ought to *work*, there are a couple of arguably neater ways of writing the same sort of operation.

This first way would work in any POSIX shell and uses the standard `case` statement:

```bash
case $signal in
    SUBSCRIPT|ITERATE|COUNTER)
        # do nothing
        ;;
    *)
        signal=SUBSCRIPT
esac
```

This `case` statement sets the value of the variable to the string `SUBSCRIPT` unless it already has one of the three values `SUBSCRIPT`, `ITERATE` or `COUNTER`.

You can write this on a single line like so:

```bash
case $signal in (SUBSCRIPT|ITERATE|COUNTER) ;; (*) signal=SUBSCRIPT; esac
```

You could also use a more compact `if` statement in `bash`:

```bash
if [[ $signal != @(SUBSCRIPT|ITERATE|COUNTER) ]]; then
    signal=SUBSCRIPT
fi
```

or, using short-circuit evaluation, if appropriate,

```bash
[[ $signal == @(SUBSCRIPT|ITERATE|COUNTER) ]] || signal=SUBSCRIPT
```

This uses an extended globbing pattern to test whether the variable's value matches any of the three mentioned values (the syntax is inherited from the `ksh` shell).  If it *doesn't* match (the test is inverted in the first variant of the code, and I'm using `||` in the second), the variable's value is reset to the string `SUBSCRIPT`.

Comment: @GillesQuénot You actually do not need to enable `extglob` to use extended globbing patterns in `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I thought that you forgot to explains

Comment: Wow. I rarely learn anything new about `bash`. And from this answer (including the comments) I just learnt four points plus was corrected in an additional one.

Answer (score 0):

For just three valid values the existing answers provide good approaches. With growing numbers this might come in handy:

```
signal=foo
default='SUBSCRIPT'
if [ -n "$signal" ]; then
    valid_values=(
        SUBSCRIPT ITERATE COUNTER
    )

    declare -A tmpar=()
    for str in "${valid_values=[@]}"; do
        tmpar[$str]=1
    done
    test -n "${tmpar["$signal"]}" || signal="$default"
else
    signal="$default"
fi
```

Comment: Cannot understand this very well.  What does `"${valid_values=[@]}"` do, and what is the use of `tmpar` ?

Comment: @Bennings `[@]` expands all elements of an indexed array: `ar=(a "b      b" c); echo "${ar[@]}`. `tmpar` is just a temporaray array.

Comment: You are testing whether value in `tmpar` is `1`, testing whether value of `signal`  is valid.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you want the variables to be assigned the value of `SUBSCRIPT` if they are unset/null:

```
ITERATE=${ITERATE:-$SUBSCRIPT}
```

Comment: I believe the variable's name was `signal` in the question, not `ITERATE`, and I took it as if the value should be reset to `SUBSCRIPT` if it did not have a value or if the value was different from the three mentioned strings.

Comment: Not before the question was edited. Your answer is much appropriate now.